# How add an ID in each day with fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Hi I have this `fullcalendar` code:

```
calendar: function(datos,rut,nombre){

    var self = this;

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        height: 500,
        events: datos,
        editable: true,

            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'prev title next',
                right: '',
            },

        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            var self = this;
            element.find('.fc-title').append(" (<strong>"+ event.estado +"</strong>)");
        },

        viewRender: function (view) {

        $('.fc-day-number').prepend("<button type='button' style='margin-right:5px; padding:0; border: none; background: none;' id ='editar_control_id' class='btn btn-default addButton' title='Ver/Editar'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button>"); 

        },

    })

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', datos);         
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');        
},
```

Using `viewRender` I add a button each day.:

```
 viewRender: function (view) {


        $('.fc-day-number').prepend("<button type='button' style='margin-right:5px; padding:0; border: none; background: none;' id ='editar_control_id' class='btn btn-default addButton' title='Ver/Editar'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button>"); 


        },
```

So, I want that each button have a day like Id:

example:

> id ='editar_control_2015-09-04_id'

this is the calendar :

[image]

How can I do this? sorry my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dayRender vs viewRender

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    // The cell has a data-date tag with the date we can use vs date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    var theDate = $(cell).data('date');
    // Find the day number td for the date
    var fcDaySkel = $("#calendar div.fc-content-skeleton td[data-date='"+theDate+"'].fc-day-number");
    fcDaySkel.prepend("<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/glyphish/glyphish/24/12-eye-icon.png' id='editar_control_"+theDate+"_id'/>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/14frdxf2/2/

This fiddle is using img instead of buttons but approach should be the same

Comment: can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551640/how-use-fullcalendar-with-a-dropdown-correctly